# Why a.storage() is b.storage() returns false when a and b reference the same data?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

```
>>> a = torch.arange(12).reshape(2, 6)
>>> a
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> b = a[1:, :]
>>> b.storage() is a.storage()
False
```

But

```
>>> b[0, 0] = 999
>>> b, a # both tensors are changed
(tensor([[999,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11]]),
 tensor([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
         [999,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11]]))
```

What is exactly the objects that stores tensor data? How can I make check if 2 tensors share memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`torch.Tensor.storage()` returns a new instance of [`torch.Storage`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/storage.html) on every invocation. You can see this in the following

```py
a.storage() is a.storage()
# False
```

To compare the pointers to the underlying data, you can use the following:

```py
a.storage().data_ptr() == b.storage().data_ptr()
# True
```

There is a discussion of how to determine whether pytorch tensors share memory in this [pytorch forum post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-way-to-check-if-two-tensors-have-the-same-base/44310/7).

---

Note the difference between `a.data_ptr()` and `a.storage().data_ptr()`. The first returns the pointer to the *first element* of the tensor, whereas the second seems to the point to the memory address of the underlying data (not the sliced view), though [it is not documented](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/storage.html#torch.FloatStorage.data_ptr).

Knowing the above, we can understand why `a.data_ptr()` is different from `b.data_ptr()`. Consider the following code:

```py
import torch

a = torch.arange(4, dtype=torch.int64)
b = a[1:]
b.data_ptr() - a.data_ptr()
# 8
```

The address of the first element of `b` is 8 more than the first element of `a` because we sliced to remove the first element, and each element is 8 bytes (the dtype is 64-bit integer).

If we use the same code as above but use an 8-bit integer data type, the memory address will be different by one.