# print the address of a GPU variable on GPU in python

Tags: python, pytorch, memory-address

I try to print the address of a variable  on GPU and CPU separately by `id()` function in `python`, but they looks close to each other in host memory, i don not know why.

```
>>> a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
>>> print(id(a))
139651301379824
>>> b = a.to('cuda:2')
>>> print(id(b))
139651301392848
```

Comment: But you are not printing the address of the device tensor in GPU memory, you are printing its address in CPU memory

Comment: @talonmies   Could you tell me how to print address of a device tensor, thanks.

Comment: I don't use Pytorch, but I would guess this is what you want (for both CPU and GPU tensors) https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.data_ptr.html#torch.Tensor.data_ptr

Answer (score 0):

You can use id(a.storage) to get the underlying storage, and you will find id(a.storage) equals id(b.storage).

And I found these links([1](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-way-to-check-if-two-tensors-have-the-same-base/44310)   [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66783542/why-a-storage-is-b-storage-returns-false-when-a-and-b-reference-the-same-dat)  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67289617/pytorch-tensor-storages-have-the-same-id-when-calling-the-storage-method)) useful and I copied the code for checking if two tensors have same base.

```
import torch
def same_storage(x, y):
    return x.storage().data_ptr() == y.storage().data_ptr()

# It works on your test.
t = torch.rand((3,3))
t1 = t[0,:]
t2 = t[:,0]

print(same_storage(t1, t2)) # prints True
 
x = torch.arange(10)
y = x[1::2]
print(same_storage(x, y)) # prints True
z = y.clone()
print(same_storage(x, z)) # prints False
print(same_storage(y, z)) # prints False
```

Comment: Hope it can help you. : )